# selecting an nested attribute to update in mongo with node driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In the following code using the Node Js Driver for MongoDB, the console log in the callback would log the number of drivers for a particular vehicle. My problem is with trying to increment the number of drivers by one with this code

```
$inc:{vehicles[vehicle_number].drivers:1}
```

It's giving me unexpected token errors with the `[` and also I'm not even sure if by starting the selector with `vehicles` it would be acting on the family that's been queried. Can you explain how I might change the code to make the increment not break the function.

```
      families.findAndModify({_id:family_id}, [],
          {$inc:{vehicles[vehicle_number].drivers:1}} , function(err, doc) {

             console.log(doc.vehicles[vehicle_number].drivers)

        })
```

**Update**
the vehicles key contains an array of vehicles. In the code above, vehicle_number represents the index in the array. I'm trying to increment the number of drivers in the findAndModify above.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5143ddf5bcf1bf4ab37da054"),
    "name"   : "Jones",
    "vehicles" : [
        {
            "make" : "Ford",
                    "year" : "2001",
            "color" : "blue",
            "registration" : "xdklde",
            "drivers" : 3
        },
                {
            "make" : "Dodge",
                    "year" : "1992",
            "color" : "green",
            "registration" : "klrv7z",
            "drivers" : 2
        },
```

Comment: It would help if you updated your question to include an example `families` document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var selector = {};
selector['vehicles.' + vehicle_number + '.drivers'] = 1;
```

then you use it in your query:

```
families.update({'_id':family_id}, {'$inc':selector} , function(err, doc) {

       console.log(doc);

});
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks, it works. any reason why you prefer update over findAndModify?